# Using variables defined in if statements

Tags: c, if-statement, scope

I'm making a program that processes a text file line by line, but the very first line of the file is a single int which tells me how many lines long the file is (header). The problem is, I'm trying to define an array to store info regarding the rest of the file, but I keep getting an undefined error on city_info and city_dist. Any idea what I'm missing?

Here's the code:

```
    while(fgets(buffer,MAX_LINE,fp)!=NULL) {
    if(firsttime){
        int num_city = atoi(buffer);
        printf("NUMBER OF CITIES = %d\n",num_city);
        node city_info[num_city]; /*compiler says these are undefined*/
        int city_dist[num_city]; /*compiler says these are undefined*/
        firsttime=FALSE;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    /*rest of code*/
```

Here's the compiler error I'm getting:

```
help.c: In function `main':
help.c:33: warning: unused variable `city_info'
help.c:34: warning: unused variable `city_dist'
help.c:41: error: `city_info' undeclared (first use in this function)
help.c:41: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
help.c:41: error: for each function it appears in.) 
help.c:42: error: `city_dist' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

edit: For those saying I've not used the variable, I've used it later on in the code

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: This is C, where you have to declare all variables at the beginning of the block.

Comment: Make it a habit to always copy the entire compile error. It will be much clearer for everyone what the question is, and you'll get better answers.

Comment: @jon; No. C99 provides a feature that you can declare elsewhere.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that arrays can't have a dynamic initialization. Use malloc instead.

Comment: That is not an error. It's a warning that you have not used the variable anywhere.

Comment: And, BTW, is this a homework thing? Do you have to use C for such tasks

Comment: @haccks: Well, without seeing any error messages (they were edited in later) one can only guess. Seems like I guessed wrong.

Comment: This is a warning, not an error - because you are not using these variables - the compiler basically is telling you their declaration is redundant.

Comment: Yep have to use C (C based course), and I've tried to assign values to the array elements and had "undefined" errors, I've changed the OP to add that in.

Comment: @user2741466: If you have working code now, please post what you did, so other people can learn from it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables defined in the scope of the if-block are not visible outside of this scope. Try this:

```
int num_city;
node *city_info = null;
int *city_dist = null;
if(firsttime) {
    num_city = atoi(buffer);
    city_info = malloc(num_city * sizeof(node));
    city_dist = malloc(num_city * sizeof(int));
    // check if malloc actually worked...

    //...
}

//...
// clean up!
if (city_info != null) free(city_info);
if (city_dist != null) free(city_dist);
```

Comment: Sorry I'm still learning C, will city_info and city_dist be defined with size only after num_city is defined? (i.e. would this break if I never gave num_city a value)

Comment: Are you compiling your program in C89 mode?

Comment: you are right. You need to allocate the buffers dynamically. read up about malloc() and free()

Comment: You real problem is, that you don't know the size of the arrays on compile time. You can not allocate them statically.

Comment: @EricSchaefer; *You real problem is, that you don't know the size of the arrays on compile time*: I don't think this is the real problem

Comment: Defining the variable outside of the if statement and then allocating memory afterwards worked perfectly. Thanks Eric!

Comment: Please don't leave this wrong code in the answer like this. This can't work, `num_city` is not set when the two arrays are defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling in C89 mode (and do not have GCC extension) then this is not valid.
But it is perfectly legal to declare variables after statements (or in any block) if your compiler supports C99 mode.

> For those saying I've not used the variable, I've used it later on in the code

Keep in mind in your case variable `num_city`, `city_info[num_city]` and `city_dist[num_city]` has block scope and you can't access them outside the `if` scope (as it is invisible to other scopes). Also, `city_info[num_city]` and `city_dist[num_city]` are **variable length arrays which is supported by C99 only**.

Answer (score -1):

You can not have declarations below statements.

```
int a = 0;

print ("%d", a);

int b = 0; //You can not declare variable here. Some compilers wont allow.
```

Comment: depends on you compiler version and standard

Comment: No. Its perfectly valid for C99.